# Wordpress Genesis theme changing the size and format of already photoshop web optimized images. Why?

Tags: seo, wordpress, images, graphics

I am very talented for 3D design and I have wonderful images I would like to share. However, logical things are not my best side and especially applied computer sciences and etc. It has nothing to with art. However not giving my art appropriate show it deserves and an appropriate website, can ruin my chances as an artist.

So I have a Wordpress website that will be very image heavy..

I have some doubts here so please if you want to help me, answer my question in a numerated way so I do not get lost. I am a noob for these things.

1. Why does my Genesis theme by studiopress keep changing the images
   compression as well as their size?
2. Why does my compression in "export for web, in photoshop even matter then when genesis changes
   it then again?"

thank you...

Answer (score 1):

The image sizes are set in functions.php and the theme will resize thumbnails and put them in the media folder. The theme will call different image sizes or thumbnails using a function call in the template.

Child themes may not show images the same and may not be centered. Themes use CSS to set the sizes of the image as rendered and there are lots of different attributes like cover and contain that change how the image fits the frame set by the size attributes.

Comment: Thank you for this answer but then what is the purpose of export for web in Photoshop? If the theme will adjust the size and compression, why not just upload lossless full resolution images to the theme? I tested it and it brings down the size and resolution and images are not that "heavy". So for Example my image when I optimize it in PS and export for web is 60kb while RAW uncompressed image uploaded to Genesis theme results in 100kb compression. 

So what the hell?! What is the point of "compressing" anything in photoshop before the upload?

Comment: The theme doesn’t do compression. I just use Shortpixel for compression and webp formats. This isn’t a photoshop forum and i don’t know why their export to web doesn’t work.

Comment: I am 100% positive Genesis theme does the compression or something... I a maximum quality jpg file and it reduces its file size, without affecting the resolution. I can even post images, screenshots and even a video if you'd want me to

Comment: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-or-decrease-wordpress-jpeg-image-compression/ Please check this link out. Wordpress does compress images

Comment: Did you try a different theme?